# Spark Streaming collect()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm using spark streaming and I have developed the following spark streaming application :

Which create an DStream from Kafka receiver (RDD1) and another one from an HTTP request (RDD2) .

My question is that I want to use the first element only from RDD1 and use it in my RDD2 and this code dosen't work in spark streaming (.first()) how can I get the same result with spark streaming 1.6

code :

```
   firstLineRDD = kvs.map(lambda x : x[0], x[1].split('\n')[0], x[2])
   dateRDD = firstLineRDD.map(lambda x : (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(x[0])/1000000),x[1],x[2]))
   dayAggRDD = dateRDD.map(lambda x : (x[0],x[1],x[2]))
   daily_date, sys , metric  = dayAggRDD.first()
   dataTSRDD = sc.parallelize(apiRequest(sys,metric,getDailyDate(daily_date)))
```

Comment: Are those `RDD` or `DStream`s ??

Comment: @massg I have modified my post im using DStreams

Comment: azelix, I still don't see the `DStreams` you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

I have used here two Kafka streams,but its almost the same as your usecase.(in java).Have converted the streams to datatsets and then you can take the first element for the first dataset and then use the values to manipulate the second one.Following is a brief abstract of the code:

```
DstreamCoord.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<Coordinates>>() {

        String valueA;
        String valueB;

        public void call(JavaRDD<Coordinates> arg0) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        RDD<Coordinates> d = arg0.rdd();

        Dataset<Row> dataset1 = session.createDataFrame(d, Coordinates.class);

        Row firstElement = dataset1.first();
            valueA = firstElement.getString(1);
            valueB = firstElement.getString(1);

            JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream2 =
                      org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                        StreamingContext,
                        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                        ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
                      );

            stream2.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String,String>>>() {

                public void call(JavaRDD<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> arg0) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Dataset<Row> dataset2 =     session.createDataFrame(arg0.rdd(), Coordinates.class);



                }
            });
```

Comment: Here i have two dataset which have two columns having say lattitude and longitude